# Sextante plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, sextante, toolbar

I'm looking for the sextant plug-in which is supposed to be showing in Plugin Manager under Manage and Install plugins. I currently have 30 plugins installed and enabled in QGIS 2.0 and 121 more showing as available so repository access looks ok. However cannot see sextant in here although have missed the obvious before. Not sure if other settings are ok. Running Windows 7.

It has been suggested a reinstall using OSGeo4W Advance mode would possibly sort this.

UPDATE: So Sextante is called Processing in QGIS 2.0. Is the Processing toolbox a separate standalone within QGIS and not directly related to the base QGIS Vector / Raster, etc tools?

Comment: A thread I just read says this is now called processing in the main QGIS interface. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, Sextante is now called Processing.

Comment: Is the Processing toolbox (the old Sextante) an expanded version of the base QGIS tools eg Vector / Raster, etc or a completely different animal. I assume a different animal with more stuff than the base tools?

Comment: Yes, it's a completely different animal. It lists all of the QGIS tools in it, but also includes GRASS, SAGA, and many other tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sextante is called Processing in QGIS 2.0 and the Processing toolbox is a separate standalone within QGIS with additional GRASS, SAGA and other tools.

Comment: It would be nice if the author would update the sextante homepage and the QGIS Python Plugins Repository page with the name change. It merely says it's deprecated.